# How to load images to several imageviews using same UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have several `UIImageViews` For each image view I want to set different images by selecting the `UIImagePicker`. Each `UIImageView` has seperate button to open the `Imagepicker`. But my problem is how I can check to which `Imageview` should I load the image inside the

`- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` delegate

Please help me. Can I set a tag or something to imagepicker within my different open galary buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possible solutions, the quickest way can be:

You can create an instance variable of `UIImageView` type. When a button clicked store corresponding `UIImageView` reference in instance variable and in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` assign image to `UIImageView` instance variable

Please let us know if it is not working in any scenario.

Comment: Im assigning to 1 imageview in the delegate like this  imgProfile.image=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; If I create instance variable from a particular ImageView Should I pass it into the delegate?

Comment: I set `UIImageView *CurrentImageView;` within my .h file. Then inside my 1st button I set CurrentImageView=imageView; but it not set the image for this. Why is that?

Comment: also In the delegate I set CurrentImageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; But its not working

Comment: It should work in case it is not working please add exact piece of code in question to help us understand where  your are mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tag to the image views. By checking tag value you can assign images to the respective image views. Try this one..